# Why instantiateItem doesn't call and ViewPager doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I try to make simple application with sliding images. I use this article http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/.

This is my xml with viewpager:
main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pages"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml with image:
item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my adapter:
ViewerPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewerPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<CueModel> mArray;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ImageView mImage;

    public ViewerPagerAdapter(Context _context){
        mContext = _context;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public void setArray(ArrayList<Bitmap> arr){
        mArray = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {  
        return POSITION_NONE;  
    }  

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
          mImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
          mImage.setImageBitmap(mArray.get(position));
          container.addView(itemView);

          return itemView;
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0.equals(arg1);
}
```

this is my activity:
OneActivity.java
(mArrays full of image)

```
public class OneActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> mArrays;
    ViewerPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main.xml);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pages);
        mAdapter = new ViewerPagerAdapter(OneActivity.this);
        mAdapter.setArrays(mArrays);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. instantiateItem doesn't call.

PS.Difference between my app and

article I have a few activity(and my arraylist initialized by items)
Thank you

Comment: You're not populating your ArrayList.

Comment: ArrayList is ok. I created and fill it by images. Just didn't write in question

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` when you fill the list?  The ViewPager won't refresh unless you tell it that there's new data.

Comment: I tried to do it. Nothing changed

Comment: I thought instantiateItem should call after setadapter

Comment: instantiateItem is called whenever the ViewPager needs a new View.  Initially, it'll call it twice for the view in the center and view in the right *if the adapter's getCount() > 0*.  That's why in your `setArray()` method you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` every time you change the array.  You also need to call it every time you add or remove items from the list.  If your array is empty in onCreate(), then getCount() is 0 so the ViewPager thinks it's empty and won't bother.

Comment: Deev can you put last comment in Answers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#instantiateItem()` is called whenever the ViewPager needs a new View. Initially, it'll call `#instantiateItem()` twice for the View in the center and view to the right if the adapter's `getCount() > 0`. That's why in your `#setArray()` method you need to call `#notifyDataSetChanged()` every time you change the array. You also need to call it every time you add or remove items from the list. If your array is empty in `#onCreate()`, then `#getCount() == 0` so the ViewPager thinks it's empty and won't bother.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is very old post but I am answering this becoz someone would get benefited. I got the same issue - `instantiateItem ()` was not getting called.
After trying so many thing I manage to finally found the mistake I did in my code and it was a silly one I forgot to set adapter to viewpager:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Don't worry, SO is out of time, so all answers is appreciate for everyone in everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For modern versions (2020+) where the error message is

Binary XML file line #(lineNumber): Error inflating class android.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)

you might want to update

android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   to

androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the size of the list was zero. Therefore, this method was not calling. When the list was not empty,  it worked properly.